# Is there any way to update XML while it was using from all pages of the website?

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net

I have an XML file, which has list of recent articles (TITLE, URL, and DESCRIPTION) and I want to update it on daily basis

**What I tried?**

1. I tried to upload it from FileZilla
2. From SERVER Plesk panel, I tried to update this file.
3. Through VB.Net code I also tried to delete and copy it from another
       folder

In all cases, an exception occurring "because it is being used by another process."
Since it is using from all articles on the website.

Is there any solution without stopping the server?

**This is the code**

```
public void getRecentPosts()
{
    try
    {
        XmlDataDocument xmldoc = new XmlDataDocument();
        XmlNodeList xmlNode;
        int i = 0;
        string post = null;
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/filename.xml"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);
        xmldoc.Load(fs);
        xmlNode = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("tagName");
        post = "<center><p><big><b>~ RECENT POSTS ~</b></big></p></center>";
        for (i = 0; i <= xmlNode.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            post = post + "<p><big><b><a href=\"" + xmlNode[i].ChildNodes.Item(1).InnerText.Trim() + "\">" + xmlNode[i].ChildNodes.Item(0).InnerText.Trim() + "</a></b></big><br /><small>" + xmlNode[i].ChildNodes.Item(2).InnerText.Trim() + "</small></p>";
        }

        divRecPost.InnerHtml = post;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex = null;
        divRecPost.InnerHtml = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why that file is always open on server? I mean once you read/write the file you should close it. So other processes can access it. 
Please release all the resources from within the code related to the file.

Comment: I am just uploading file and reading on all pages just to display recent comments after the content.

Comment: If I close the file after reading and display the content and close it, problem will be resolved? I think I forget to close it.

Comment: Yes, server is constantly utilizing this file. You have to close the file from within server to be able to replace it.

Comment: I update the code kindly see and let me know what object should be closed

Comment: FileStream object fs must be closed at the end.

`fs.Close();`
`fs.Dispose();`

Comment: Thank you very much just doing this and updating you soon.

Comment: Or just wrap the stream in a using block, which calls Dispose automatically. Probably shouldn't be using XmlDataDocument, though, since it's deprecated.

Comment: @ZeeshanAliKhan Thank you very much problem has been fixed, I would love and greatful, if you become a part of our website www . includehelp . com as reviewer or editorial to share tips and tricks

Comment: @VinyGoyal How can I join?

Comment: @ZeeshanAliKhan sorry for the late reply, send your contact details to contact page of www. includehelp. com

Comment: @VinyGoyal Message sent.